# Change file icon based on default program

Tags: 16.04, icons, csv

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial and this one is alluding me ever since I started using Ubuntu.

**Question:** How do I change file icons based on default program? To phrase it in a different way, how can I mass-change file icons not based on their mimetype?

**Context:**
The mimetype for `CSV` files is `text/plain` for which ubuntu displays a plain text icon. I normally open CSV files in Libre Office Calc because of obvious reasons so it would be natural to identify CSV files as being related to Libre Office Calc visually as well.

I know I can change the icon of a particular file type by creating a new mimetype for it but I wonder if doing that will keep all other CSV related operations as they were. e.g.,

- will I be able to preview CSV files in email attachments in Evolutoin the same way (by single clicking it)?
- If I upload a CSV from my PC to a server, is the server going to identify the CSV file as `text/plain` correctly?
- Are there going to be any implications that I would not notice right away but would have a negative effect on my system?

I'm open to the idea of creating a non-standard mimetype for any file extension as long it doens't mess up the system.

Please advise

Comment: Who voted it to close???

Comment: The correct mimetype is `text/csv`